# why setting a property in Objective-C instance method with self and without self shows different result?

Tags: objective-c, string

I have just started learning Objective-C and I am confused with the output. Trying to understand the usage of self with properties inside an instance method. Why setting a property in Objective-C instance method with self and without self shows different result?

I declared the property with copy attribute and assuming the assignment to the property will be a copy rather than a direct reference.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface AddressCard : NSObject

//using a copy attribute
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString *Name, *Email;

-(void) setName:(NSString *) name andEmail: (NSString *) email;
-(void) print;

@end
```

In the implementation setName instance method, I am using self.Name and self.Email to set the property values

```
@implementation AddressCard

@synthesize Name;
@synthesize Email;

-(void) setName:(NSString *) name andEmail:(NSString *)email
{
    self.Name = name;
    self.Email = email;
}

-(void) print
{
    NSLog(@"Name : %@ , Email: %@", Name, Email);
}
@end
```

In the main program, I pass NSMutableString to setName instance method, then call print and then I modify the name mutable string variable and call print again.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "AddressCard.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {
        
        AddressCard *card = [[AddressCard alloc] init];
        
        //declaring local mutable string variables to use them for passing as parameters
        //to setName instance method
        NSMutableString *name = [NSMutableString stringWithString: @"John Doe"];
        NSMutableString *email = [NSMutableString stringWithString: @"john.doe@email.com"];
        
        //passing the name and email mutables as parameters
        [card setName: name andEmail: email];
        
        [card print];
        
        //Modifying name variable which previously passed as parameter to setName method 
        [name appendString: @" MODIFIED"];
        
        NSLog(@"Output Should Not Change");
        
        //Print again      
        [card print];

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Modification to name mutable string variable in the main program does not impact the second line result.

> Name : John Doe , Email: john.doe@email.com
>
> Output Should Not Change
>
> Name : John Doe , Email: john.doe@email.com

But If I modify the setName instance method by removing the self and directly set the property Name and Email, I don't get same output.

```
-(void) setName:(NSString *) name andEmail:(NSString *)email
{
   // self.Name = name
   Name = name;
   // self.Email = email;
   Email = email;
}
```

Modification to the mutable name variable in main program is reflected in the output.

> Name : John Doe , Email: john.doe@email.com
>
> Output Should Not Change
>
> Name : **John Doe MODIFIED**, Email: john.doe@email.com

Can anyone explain why? I am under the impression that whether I use self. or no, I am accessing the same instance property and assigning the value, so output should not change.

Comment: This is tangental, but FYI standard practice in obj-c is to start variable names with a lower-case letter, and start class names with a capital letter. so your Name and Email properties should be name and email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am under the impression that whether I use self. or no, I am accessing the same instance property and assigning the value

The same instance variable, yes, but not in the same way. By using `self.name` you are calling the setter method which is implementing the `copy` that you have specified on the property. Conversely, by setting the instance variable directly you aren't copying, so when the mutable string is changed it is changed everywhere.

So, the alternate to using `self.` in this case is:

```
Name = [name copy];
```

because this respects what your property definition says you're going to do.